# WinApi - PeekMessage Always Returns False

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, peekmessage

I can't get PeekMessage to work. Actually I would expect it to flood me with messages but it's return value is 0.

I use a WinForm, start a background thread that is peeking messages and use the window with the mouse. The window is usable like always but no messages can be peeked. What am I doing wrong ? Last error is 0 all the time.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NativeMessage
{
    public IntPtr handle;
    public uint msg;
    public IntPtr wParam;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public uint time;
    public Point p;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return handle + ", " + msg + ", " + wParam + ", " + lParam + ", " + time + ", " + p;
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int PeekMessage(out NativeMessage lpMsg, IntPtr window, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax, uint wRemoveMsg);

public Form1()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => run());
}

private void run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; )
    {
        NativeMessage a = new NativeMessage();
        int c = PeekMessage(out a, IntPtr.Zero, (uint) 0, (uint) 0, (uint) 0);
        if (c != 0)
            trace(" -> " + c); // prints strings
    }
}
```

**Solved:**

- I called `Show()` in the main thread to show my form
- and redirected the main thread to log the messages
- (not XY problem, I needed PeekMessage to work or at least to understand how to use it)

*(thanks for showing me the error I made)*

Comment: Based upon your code, you do not create a window on that thread. Why would you expect any messages in the thread's queue?

Comment: @Noseratio There is no requirement for a thread to own any windows to receive messages. There is [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx) after all.

Comment: @IInspectable, I don't see that anywhere in the code above. That's why I asked why OP expects a flood of messages.

Comment: @Noseratio If you print all messages that are posted to WndProc it is quite a flood.

Comment: @mini-me, correct, but you do not create a window inside your `run()` thread, do you? At least, not in the code above. A thread can't pump messages posted to a window belonging to another thread. Also, it doesn't look to me like a good idea using a pool thread for your message loop. You should create a new child thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window message queues are per-thread unless associated in some way (`AttachThreadInput`, window parent relationship...)

Answer (score 6):

When you pass `NULL` (i.e. 0) for the `hWnd` parameter, the `PeekMessage` function retrieves thread messages, and messages for any window that belongs to the current thread. This is called out explicitly in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx):

> *hWnd* [in, optional]
>
> > A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window must belong to the current thread.
> >
> > If hWnd is `NULL`, `PeekMessage` retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current thread's message queue whose *hwnd* value is `NULL` (see the [`MSG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx) structure). Therefore if *hWnd* is `NULL`, both window messages and thread messages are processed.

Since you are calling this function on a new thread in a ThreadPool, there are no messages for it to retrieve. That thread is not associated with any windows and has no messages.

The function returns `FALSE` (i.e. 0) when there are no messages available.

If you were calling `PeekMessage` on the main UI thread (the one associated with your form), you would be getting a peek at all messages destined for your form window.

Comment: Well, I actually read that thread note but since every window has it's own thread I was confused how 1 thread can peek messages of other windows as the parameter note states. And I just want to log all messages via PeekMessage and let them be translated by the API itself.

Comment: @mini Every window does *not* have its own thread. In fact, the general situation is almost exactly the opposite: every window runs on a *single* thread; it is called the UI thread. And to answer your other question, a thread can peek messages of other windows by passing in the handle of the window of interest.

Comment: PeekMessage is not a good logging mechanism, certainly not how you're using it. There are better ways of doing it, but that's an entirely different question. I would have answered that one, had you asked it. Do beware of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).