# PeekMessage always returns FALSE

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, peekmessage

I have written a small test application that inserts files (with hardcoded paths) into the currently active folder/application via delayed rendering. It works as expected. But I have a question - why does `PeekMessage` always return `FALSE`? But if you remove the `PeekMessage` call, `Wndproc` will never be called. I read a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317210/winapi-peekmessage-always-returns-false), but I'm creating a window in the same thread in which I'm trying to process messages.

Code:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WindProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (Msg) {      
        case WM_RENDERALLFORMATS: {
            OpenClipboard(hWnd);
            EmptyClipboard(); 
        }
        case WM_RENDERFORMAT: {
            printf("WM_RENDERFORMAT received");
            
            <Here the file paths are copied to the clipboard>

            if (Msg == WM_RENDERALLFORMATS)
                CloseClipboard();
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD:
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND hwnd_;

void thread_(void* ignored) {
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = { 0 };
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WindProc;
    wcx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wcx.lpszClassName = TEXT("my_class");
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);

    hwnd_ = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("my_class"), TEXT(""), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    MSG msg;
    while (true) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) {
            printf("PeekMessage returned TRUE\n");
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            break;
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

void main() {
    CloseHandle((HANDLE)_beginthread(thread_, 0, NULL));

    // let's give some time to thread to create msg window
    Sleep(100);

    if (OpenClipboard(hwnd_)) {
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, NULL);
        CloseClipboard();
    }

    while (true) {
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not planning on using the clipboard for inter-thread data passing, that's totally inappropriate.

Comment: Does `CreateWindowEx` succeed?

Comment: Of course, otherwise nothing would have worked

Comment: Definitely worth adding in all the missing error checking (don't ignore return values). But maybe `PeekMessage` returns `FALSE` because there are no queued messages. It's either that or the window handle is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But as I wrote - this is test app. `hwnd_` is valid - I had debug messages but deleted them for better code readability.

Comment: Also note that your message queue is going to fill up over time, since you're never draining it. Probably a good idea to get a standard Windows application working, and deal with more involved topics like multithreading once you've got a firm grasp on the fundamentals.

Comment: Yes, it could be solved by using `PM_REMOVE` instead `PM_NOREMOVE` (or adding `GetMessage` call). But my question is why `PeekMessage` always returns FALSE?

Comment: What messages do you expect to arrive? It's a message-only window, and there are apparently no (broadcast) messages in your system. [`WM_RENDERALLFORMATS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-renderallformats) and [`WM_RENDERFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-renderformat) are sent to the clipboard owner, and your message-only window isn't.

Comment: Yes, but why `WM_RENDERFORMAT` doesn't comes without `PeekMessages`?

Comment: Presumably because `PeekMessage` dispatches cross-thread sent messages (see [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983)).

Comment: @IInspectable "*and your message-only window isn't [the clipboard owner]*" - it should be, since it is being passed to `OpenClipboard()` and then `EmptyClipboard()` would assign it as the owner. Unless `hwnd_` is still `NULL` when `OpenClipboard()` is called. A `Sleep()` loop is not a good way to wait for a window to be created. I would move `SetClipboardData()` into the worker thread after the window is created. Or at least have the worker thread signal an event that the main thread waits for before then calling `SetClipboardData()`.

Comment: @Liverpoolfan on a side note, have you read [What is the proper handling of WM_RENDERFORMAT and WM_RENDERALLFORMATS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121224-00/?p=5763) yet?

Comment: Yes, a `Sleep()` is not a good way, but it's good enough for the test app and it works. And I need `SetClipboardData()` in a main thread, because it's simulate needs of my main (for which I am trying to develop this functionality) application. And yes,  message-only window is definitely is clipboard owner in this case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, regarding your last question - yes, I read a lot, but not this topic. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: Never put sleep in a message loop. That break there is also wrong, break on WM_QUIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PeekMessage()` (and `GetMessage()`) only returns messages that are *posted* via `PostMessage()` or `PostThreadMessage()` to the calling thread's message queue.  `PeekMessage()` returns FALSE when there is no *posted* message available at the moment it is called. `GetMessage()` blocks until a *posted* message becomes available.

However, the messages in question (`WM_RENDERFORMAT` and `WM_RENDERALLFORMATS`) are instead being *sent* via `SendMessage...()` directly to the target window. But, the messages are being sent by another thread, so `PeekMessage()` (or `GetMessage()`) is still needed, as they internally dispatch messages that are *sent* across thread boundaries.

This is stated in [`PeekMessage()`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea):

> **Dispatches incoming nonqueued messages**, checks the thread message queue for a posted message, and retrieves the message (if any exist).
>
> ...
>
> **During this call, the system dispatches (`DispatchMessage`) pending, nonqueued messages, that is, messages sent to windows owned by the calling thread using the `SendMessage`, `SendMessageCallback`, `SendMessageTimeout`, or `SendNotifyMessage` function.** Then the first queued message that matches the specified filter is retrieved. The system may also process internal events. If no filter is specified, messages are processed in the following order:
>
> - **Sent messages**
> - Posted messages
> - Input (hardware) messages and system internal events
> - **Sent messages (again)**
> - WM_PAINT messages
> - WM_TIMER messages

As well as the [`GetMessage()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage):

> Retrieves a message from the calling thread's message queue. **The function dispatches incoming sent messages until a posted message is available for retrieval.**
>
> ...
>
> **During this call, the system delivers pending, nonqueued messages, that is, messages sent to windows owned by the calling thread using the `SendMessage`, `SendMessageCallback`, `SendMessageTimeout`, or `SendNotifyMessage` function.** Then the first queued message that matches the specified filter is retrieved. The system may also process internal events. If no filter is specified, messages are processed in the following order:
>
> - **Sent messages**
> - Posted messages
> - Input (hardware) messages and system internal events
> - **Sent messages (again)**
> - WM_PAINT messages
> - WM_TIMER messages

And [`SendMessage()`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage):

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. **If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code.** The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message. However, the sending thread will process incoming nonqueued messages while waiting for its message to be processed. To prevent this, use `SendMessageTimeout` with `SMTO_BLOCK` set. For more information on nonqueued messages, see [Nonqueued Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues).

---

With that said, your handling of the `WM_RENDERALLFORMATS` message is wrong.  For one thing, it must not call `EmptyClipboard()`, and for another, it is not checking whether your app is still the clipboard owner before rendering its data.  See [What is the proper handling of WM_RENDERFORMAT and WM_RENDERALLFORMATS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121224-00/?p=5763) for why these points are important.

Also, you have a race condition in your main thread. Before it calls `OpenClipboard()`, it sleeps for only 100ms to wait for the window to be created first, but there is no guarantee that `hwnd_` will have been assigned within that 100ms. It could take that long just for the worker thread to start running, for instance.

A better option is to have the worker thread signal an event when the window is created, and then have the main thread wait on that event (even better would be to simply move the initial `SetClipboardData()` call into the worker thread itself after creating the window, but you have dismissed that option).

Try something more like this instead:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WindProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {      

        /*
        case WM_CREATE:
            if (OpenClipboard(hWnd)) {
                EmptyClipboard();
                SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, NULL);
                CloseClipboard();
            }
            return 0;
        }
        */

        case WM_RENDERALLFORMATS: {
            if (OpenClipboard(hWnd)) {
                if (GetClipboardOwner() == hWnd) {
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_RENDERFORMAT, CF_HDROP, 0);
                }
                CloseClipboard();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_RENDERFORMAT: {
            printf("WM_RENDERFORMAT received");            
            if (wParam == CF_HDROP) {
                // <Here the file paths are copied to the clipboard>
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD:
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND hwnd_ = NULL;

void thread_(void* arg) {
    HANDLE hEvent = (HANDLE)arg;

    WNDCLASSEX wcx = { 0 };
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WindProc;
    wcx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wcx.lpszClassName = TEXT("my_class");
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);

    hwnd_ = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("my_class"), TEXT(""), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    SetEvent(hEvent);

    if (hwnd_ == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        printf("GetMessage returned a message\n");
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

int main() {
    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!hEvent)
        return 1;

    uintptr_t res = _beginthread(thread_, 0, hEvent);
    if (res == -1L) {
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
        return 1;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hEvent);

    if (hwnd_ != NULL) {
        if (OpenClipboard(hwnd_)) {
            EmptyClipboard();
            SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, NULL);
            CloseClipboard();
        }
    }

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)res;
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INIFINTE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why does `PeekMessage` always return `FALSE`?

Assuming that the window handle that you pass to `PeekMessage` is valid, then the reason for `PeekMessage` returning `FALSE` is simply that there are no messages in the queue.

That this is the case can be discerned from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea) which says:

> If a message is available, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If no messages are available, the return value is zero.